# Where do transcendent items drop?

Tags: dungeon-defenders

In dungeon defenders which maps/gameplay modes cause transcendent items to drop? I've seen mythical gear drop on nightmare playthroughs, but so far the only transcendent gear I've seen has been in shops or donated by friendly users.

What's the secret to transcendent drops? Are they just very rare in the places where mythical gear might drop, or are there more specific criteria for having them drop?

Answer (score 3):

Just so you know I have never personally played Dungeon Defenders but I did do some research for you.

I [found](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=4&ved=0CEcQFjAD&url=http%3A%2F%) that Transcendent Items/Gear (not sure what you call it) drops in the same places as any Mythical Gear/Items. I hope this helps if you were hoping for a better answer I can look deeper.

---

I did some more research for you and I [found](http://forums.trendyent.com/showthread.php?51733-Confirmed-Transcendent-Drops) that items drop from,

- Über Monster Fest
- Uber Monster Fest 2
- Oasis Monster Fest

And the following campaign/Quest for the Lost Eternia Shards maps in Nightmare Hardcore Mixed Mode Survival;

- Mistymire forest
- Moraggo Desert Town
- Alchemical Laboratory
- Hall of Court
- Endless Spires

Apparently around wave 20 is when you start finding Transcendent gear, according to this [thread on the Trendy forum](http://forums.trendyent.com/showthread.php?50706-Best-place-to-find-Transcendent-gear).

Comment: any chance i can get a comment with that downvote please?

Comment: I wasn't downvoter, but your link is broken and I was hoping for something authoritative (and ideally a guaranteed way to get some, e.g. as rewards on specific map+difficulty)

Comment: hmmm guess ill work on fixing that

Comment: Mythical gear drop from a lot of places where there is no chance of getting transcendent gear, so this answer could nearly just have said it drops where gear drops

Comment: like i said never played only answered from what i found, which i guess is nothing since the link didnt work.

Comment: "patience is a virtue" i planned on fixing it.

Comment: Looks better but needs some formatting, I'm on mobile atm, will look at it when I get home

Comment: Hmm I know what quite a few of those acronyms mean, but UMF OMF and MGO are lost on me.

Comment: UMF is ultimate monster fest, I don't know OMF and MGO though, its been a while since I played

Comment: OMF is oasis monster fest and I think MGO is the campaign level in the second expansion

Comment: MGO would stand for [Moraggo](http://dungeondefenders.wikia.com/wiki/Moraggo_Desert_Town), which is indeed the map in the second Shards DLC. What the current answer doesn't seem to be made clear is that the first listed Survival maps have to be set to the second listed difficulties - they're not two separate lists of maps.

Answer (score 2):

I found that if you do most Eternia Shard Quests on insane or nightmare survival, around way 15-20 monsters start dropping transcendent gear. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Survival:

- Mistymire forest
- Moraggo Desert Town
- Karithiki Jungle (spelling)
- Aquanos (supreme here)

Trans pets on the monsterfests, never seen a trans drop on Alc Labs. Maybe I'll have another look sometime.

Comment: Any idea what the minimum survival levels are?